# how to add legends and values in a Venn diagram using R (VennEuler package)?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I've been looking for the best way to make Venn diagrams with multiple proportional fields and so far I've been considered the best tool is venneuler from R, but I have modified the code a lot to present it exactly as I need it and I have not been able to get the format I need

With this code:

```
library(rJava)
library(venneuler)
vd <- venneuler(c(A=0.3, B=0.3, C=1.1, "A&B"=0.1, "A&C"=0.2, "B&C"=0.1, "A&B&C"=0.1))
plot(vd)
title("Something")
```

I obtain this:

[image: Diagram that I have get so far]

I've added the legends in so many ugly ways but I don like any. Also, I need to obtain the respective values in the respective fields. The image that I need I edited it in a image editor. 
what I want is something like:

[image: Cool image]

If you can recommend me another tool or help me with the code I will really appreciate it
Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41027549/1691723

Comment: It might be helpful to get a hang on handling gList object from venn functions.

Comment: use calculate.overlap to get the labels for each circle. For example `overlap <- calculate.overlap(x = list('a' = letters[1:5], 'b' = letters[1:10], 'c' = letters[1:15]));`    `sapply(overlap, length)`

Comment: look at the source code of `calculate.overlap` to understand the output of this function. It is very straight forward....

Comment: Thanks, I will check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished with my r package [eulerr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=eulerr).

```
library(eulerr)

vd <- euler(c(A = 0.3, B = 0.3, C = 1.1,
              "A&B" = 0.1, "A&C" = 0.2, "B&C" = 0.1,
              "A&B&C" = 0.1))
plot(vd, key = TRUE, counts = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Now looks like relevant plotting code (in the most recent version) is now:
```plot(vd, legend = TRUE, quantities= TRUE)```