# Venn Diagrams with `venneuler` in `R`: delete the name of the set from the plot and add elements name

Tags: r, venn-diagram

For the past few days I have been trying to figure out how to draw a Venn diagram from an arbitrary number of sets and came across the `R` package `venneuler`. This code:

```
genes <- paste("gene",1:20,sep="")

df = data.frame(term=character(), class=character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (k in 1:15) {
  df2=data.frame(term=sample(genes,10), class = rep(paste("class ",k,sep=""),10), stringsAsFactors = 
  FALSE)
  df<-rbind(df,df2)
}


library(rJava)
library(UpSetR)
library(tidyverse)
library(venneuler)
library(grid)

v <- venneuler(df)

par(cex = 0.5) 
plot(v)
```

produces a figure like this:

[image]

This figure was just what I was looking for. Anyway, I would like to remove the name of the set (class 1, class 2 etc.) from the plot, and instead add the elements (e.g. gene1, gene2) contained within each set.

Comment: This is perhaps relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165493/how-to-add-legends-and-values-in-a-venn-diagram-using-r-venneuler-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could directly modify `v$labels`:

```r
library(venneuler)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

v <- venneuler(df)

par(cex = 0.5) 

# Create the list of genes per class
classgenes <- df %>% group_by(class) %>% 
                     summarize(labels = paste(stringr::str_sort(term,numeric=T),collapse = '\n'))  %>%
                     ungroup 


# Order the class new label according to v$labels order
newlabels <- left_join(data.frame(class = v$labels), classgenes)
#> Joining, by = "class"

# Modify the labels
v$labels <- newlabels$labels

plot(v)
```

[image]

Comment: @Mark, did I understand correctly your question?

Comment: Yes! Thank you :-)